# Depurar módulo Prestashop con NetBeans, punto de interrupción no alcanzado

Tags: netbeans, xampp, prestashop, depuración, xdebug

Estoy desarrollando un módulo de Prestashop con XAMPP (3.2.2, puerto 8080), NetBeans (8.2) y XDebug (2.5.5, incluido en XAMPP). El problema es que no se detiene en el punto de interrupción que establezco en el módulo.

He hecho una pequeña web en PHP (no Prestashop) para probar si se puede depurar y efectivamente se detiene en los puntos de interrupción.

Si configuro en NetBeans la opción "Stop at First Line" a True la depuración se detiene en `index.php` y puedo depurar línea a línea con <kbd>F7</kbd> en Prestashop. Pero no pasa por el módulo.

Esta es la configuración en `php.ini` para XDebug en XAMPP:

```
[XDebug]  
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"  
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug  
xdebug.profiler_enable=1  
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"  
xdebug.remote_autostart=1  
xdebug.remote_enable=1  
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp  
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1  
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug_error_log"  
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

El log de XDebug no muestra errores e indica que se ha establecido el punto de interrupción:

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 4468 -t line -s enabled -f file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/prestashop_1_6_1_17/admin/modules/mymodule/mymodule.php -n 218
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4468" state="enabled" id="119560449"></response>
```

Este es código fuente (extraído de: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module)

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
  exit;
}

class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodule';
        $this->tab = 'shipping_logistics';
        $this->version = '0.0.1';
        $this->author = 'Oliver';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME')) {
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
        }
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }

        if (!parent::install() ||
            !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') ||
            !$this->registerHook('header') ||
            !Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my module')
        ) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
    }    

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() ||
            !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = null;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name)) {
            $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('MYMODULE_NAME'));
            if (!$my_module_name
                || empty($my_module_name)
                || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name))
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
            else {
                Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', $my_module_name);
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
            }
        }
        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }    

    public function displayForm()
    {
        // Get default language
        $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

        // Init Fields form array
        $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                    'name' => 'MYMODULE_NAME',
                    'size' => 20,
                    'required' => true
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            )
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();

        // Module, token and currentIndex
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

        // Language
        $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

        // Title and toolbar
        $helper->title = $this->displayName;
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
        $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
        $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
            'save' =>
            array(
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ),
            'back' => array(
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
            )
        );

        // Load current value
        $helper->fields_value['MYMODULE_NAME'] = Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME');

        return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
    }
}
```

Para depurar lo que he hecho es crear un Proyecto "PHP Application with Existing Sources" que apunte directamente a la web de Prestashop local "C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop_1_6_1_17\admin" que se ejecuta en el navegador.

Comment: ¿Lo instancias y usas en algún sitio? Si no, no se ejecutará el código del módulo nunca.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Entiendo que sí porque puedo ver la página de configuración del módulo e interactuar con ella. He puesto puntos de interrupción en las funciones `getContent` y `displayForm` que son las que se encargan de mostrar la página de configuración del módulo.

Comment: ¿Estás usando herencia o sobrecarga en tu clase? No sé cómo funciona prestashop pero, ¿es posible que esté sobrecargando tu clase en algún lado en vez de usar la tuya?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Soy un poco nuevo en Prestashop y no sabría decir exactamente cómo se utiliza la clase dado que el mismo Prestashop se encarga de utilizarla :(

Comment: ¿Estás depurando el PHP que desarrollas o la copia que instala en el servidor Prestashop cuando lo instalas? Si intentas depurar el original no conseguirás nada. Si depuras la copia entonces debería estar funcionando. Si sigue sin funcionar entonces podría ser debido a que prestashop usa tu módulo a través de alguna sobrecarga y no de forma directa.

Comment: Aún no tienes reputación suficiente para usar el chat de stackoverflow, pero si lo deseas te puedo facilitar mi telegram o hangouts por si deseas una conversación más fluida.

Comment: Estoy viendo que por lo visto mi suposición podría ser cierta y prestashop no usa directamente tu clase, si no que crea una sobrecarga en `/override/classes` cuando instalas tu módulo, a parte de que realiza una copia de éste durante la instalación. ¿Podrías comprobarlo?

Comment: @OscarGarcia He mirado en la ruta que indicas y no parece haber una sobrecarga del módulo. Los directorios tienen un `index.php` que contiene información de los `headers` sin más código. Por lo que entiendo de la documentación de Prestashop el directorio `/override/classes` se utiliza para overridar comportamientos por defecto (http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

Comment: Vi esta entrada en el foro: [https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/181779-debugging-prestashop-modules-with-eclipse-pdt-and-xdebug/](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/181779-debugging-prestashop-modules-with-eclipse-pdt-and-xdebug/) que dice: *If you are trying to debug class override, these overrides get copied to the folder /overrides/class/yourclass. The file that you provide in the module itself is actualy never used, so **you have to set breakpoints on the copied ones**.*

Comment: Lástima :( pensaba que sería un solución pero es del 2014 y no sé si aplica a versiones anteriores de Prestashop (yo estoy con 1.6 y 1.7). He comprobado `/overrides/class/yourclass` (aunque realmente el directorio `class` es `classes`) y no he encontrado mi módulo ahí, sólo archivos `index.php`. He comprobado todo el directorio `overrides` y no veo nada que me indique me mi módulo esté ahí. Finalmente he buscado en la raíz de prestashop el archivo `mymodule.php` y solo lo encuentra en "C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop_1_6_1_17\modules\mymodule".

Comment: Pues la última esperanza sería escribir en su foro una consulta o bien depurar paso a paso desde el `index.php` para ver en qué punto entra en juego tu módulo, aunque podría ser una tarea ardua. Siento no disponer de tiempo de hacerme una instalación local de prestashop para probar :(

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a insertar un [`xdebug_break()`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_break) en el código? Si no me equivoco se detendrá la ejecución y netbeans podría decirte en qué script ha realizado la parada (para saber si se ha hecho una copia a otro sitio o dónde se está realizando dicho punto de ruptura).

Comment: He escrito en StackOverflow en inglés, pero de momento nadie ha contestado. Con `xdebug_break()` se ha parado la ejecución...Esperaba no tener que modificar código para depurarlo. Si no hay otro remedio pues lo haré así, pero me parece curioso que no se pare la ejecución mediante un punto de interrupción y sí lo haga con la instrucción.

Comment: ¿Se ha parado en tu archivo o en otro diferente? Fíjate bien en la ruta del archivo que depura para ver si es el tuyo o una copia de él. Si es el mismo archivo podría deberse algún problema de configuración.

Comment: Es el mismo archivo porque he puesto `xdebug_break()` justo encima de los puntos de interrupción que tenía establecidos en NetBeans. Además la ruta que aparece al pasar por encima del código indica que es el mismo archivo.

Comment: Entonces podría tratarse de un problema de configuración. Llegado a este punto tampoco tengo experiencia de xdebug en xampp, sólo uso Linux :( ¡suerte con la pregunta en SO en inglés!

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Al menos puedo ir haciendo con `xdebug_break()`, menos es nada :)

Comment: No borres la pregunta. Nunca se sabe cuándo puede llegar alguien con la respuesta :) la he marcado como favorita, también me interesa saberlo.

Comment: Ahí queda para la posteridad :)